# Restrict certain character combinations in username during registration

Tags: user-registration, content-restriction, username

I am trying to restrict a certain combination of characters in a user name while they register.

I have restricted user names to numeric characters only, but now I am not getting a way out to restrict certain combination & numeric values for user names.

Here is the code I'm using, which enforces numeric only user names:

```
'username' => array(
                'label' => __('Username', 'peepso-core'),
                'descript' => __('Numeric Username Only, Best would be Your Mobile Number', 'peepso-core'),
                'value' => $input->val('username', ''),
                'required' => 1,
                'validation' => array(
                    'numeric',
                    'required',
                    'minlen:' . PeepSoUser::USERNAME_MINLEN,
                    'maxlen:' . PeepSoUser::USERNAME_MAXLEN,
                    'custom'
                ),
```

Please suggest what can be done.

Comment: Where are you using this array? I'm not familiar with any WordPress mechanism that accepts such data in order to customize registration.

Comment: @bosco i have a plugin called PeepSo and it uses the individual registration form, where i want to restrict username combination like 0000000001 and so on, any kind of combination which is not normal.

Comment: I am leaving this question open because i am not able to get answer even i have done every experiment. nothing is coming out